# IBM Informix driver client ERROR: Incorrect password or user [UN]@[IP][CompName] is not known on the database server

Tags: .net, informix

I downloaded the correct version of Client SDK by [IBM DOC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016673),
Now, I tried to ways to connect Informix readonly database (UCCX of cisco):

1. ODBC
2. .NET DLL (IBM.Data.Informix.dll)

Both gave me the following Error:

> IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException: ERROR [28000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Incorrect password or user [UserNameComesHere]@[MyCompIPComesHere][myCompFullDomainNameComesHere] is not known on the database server.

things that changed from last time i've succeeded to get information:

1. I upgraded the OS to Windows 10
2. I changed the driver respectively
3. Also i know same connection string worked before
4. most important: **if the driver was'nt concatinate an *ip* and *compFullName* probably it was worked.**

Thanks A Lot for who can share additional information.

[image]

Comment: That message is returned by the server using all the information it gets, It doesn't mean that it's taking the ip/fqdn as part of the password ;)

I suggest to check with something like ilogin (should be in your CSDK directory), if that work then move to ODBC.  Also, try with other users, it will tell you if is generic or just for that particular user. On Windows the Informix ODBC driver has a limit on how big the password can be, I don't remember how long, but I know is less than Linux/Unix.

Comment: 18 chars for old versions, 32 for new

Comment: the password is 10 chars. i've tried ilogin and i've got error "database:sqlcode = -951" do you know where to find the meaning of that?

Comment: -951 is "username is not known on the database server". You can find the text message for any error running the finderr.exe utility.
If you can' connect with ilogin, there is no point on testing with odbc or .net, it will fail. I suggest to check on the server itself (database server) with dbaccess (another informix tool). If you run "dbaccess -> Connection -> Connect -> [database server]" it will ask you for username and password. Don't leave them blank, try using the same info you used from ilogin.

Comment: this app doesn't work here, by the way the connection get same error from windows server 2012 r2 also

Comment: when dealing with auth errors is better to go back to basic. Testing directly on the server (dbaccess->connect->user/passw) will tell you if there is a problem there removing the client side from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turns out to be the wrong password used for that user. However, after I changed the password on the Linux server where Informix 12.10 was installed, I still got the same connection error message. I had to restart Informix instance via `onmode -u` followed by `onmode -m` to make it work.  So it appears that Informix has user authentication info cached somehow.